# Scroll navigation bar transparent on the right side?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am attaching a picture below. Basically, there is a navigation bar with list items. Overflow-y is scroll as you can see, we can scroll to the right (and then left). I would like to make only the right side transparent before scrolling, just like in the picture. And then when I get to the end, only the left side should be transparent. Is this somehow possible in CSS? I am using ReactJS for this website (mobile-first approach as seen in the picture), so if I need to use React here instead of CSS, that's okay too. Waiting for the kind replies, thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you attach you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of some almost new CSS feature as clipping/masking:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 90%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))
```

If you can add any code we could be more precise.

Comment: this one is working. also, i went on the official React website, turned on developer tools, set it to a mobile device, inspected the list item on the top (has the same transparent effect on the left and right) and i could use their css code. :) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: hidden` and `:pseudo` elements on the navigation bar to create a gradient

```css
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ccc;
}
nav::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240, 244, 245, 0), rgba(240, 244, 245, 1));
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  <a href="#">Item 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: this looks great. is it possible to do the same on the left side?